# add multiple items to a header Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word

Tags: c#, .net, ms-word, office-interop

I am building up a word document programatically and the final thing for me to do is to add a header which contains an image to the left a title in the middle.

I have tried various different things but nothing is working. I have tried adding a table to the header range (this throws an exception). I have tried adding the image and then the text but this just makes the text appear and not the image. I have tried adding new fields to the header range but this doesn't work neither.

Could someone point me in the correct direction?

```
//Add header into the document
foreach (Section section in document.Sections)
{
    //Get the header range and add the header details.
    Range headerRange = section.Headers
    [WdHeaderFooterIndex.wdHeaderFooterPrimary].Range;
    headerRange.InlineShapes.AddPicture(@"C:\Development\Tools\CommentParser\CommentParser\HeaderLogo.png");
    headerRange.Font.ColorIndex = WdColorIndex.wdBlue;
    headerRange.Font.Size = 10;
    headerRange.Text = "Title";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution to my problem. It is rather silly if you ask me but if you have headerRange.Text before the image then it will display them both and the text will be to the right of the image. If I have headerRange.Text second as it is in my sample text then it will just display the text.

Although I have solved it, if someone could please explain why this happens then it would be much appreciated.